# Blackjack game using dice

Tags: java, dice, blackjack

I'm doing a project in java in which I am using dice to simulate a blackjack game, however, I have hit an area where I have written the wrong code. I'm trying to get the dealer to simulate actions if the players score is higher than his. Also my `checkWinner()` method seems to be coming active at the wrong time. I'm not asking anyone to fix it but rather tell me where the code is wrong.

```
public class BlackJack {

    static PairOfDice cards = new PairOfDice();
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System. in );
    static int playerScore, dealerScore, player, dealer, tempScore;
    static boolean newGame;
    static String play, hit;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        newGame();
        dealerRoll();
        playerRoll();

        // checkWinner();
    }

    public static void newGame() {

        System.out.println("Would you like to play blackjack? y or n?");
        play = scan.nextLine();

        if (play == "y"); {
            newGame = true;
        }
        if (play != "y") newGame = false;
    }

    public static void dealerRoll() {
        while (newGame) {
            cards.rollDice();
        }

        dealerScore = (cards.rollDice());
        System.out.println("Dealer score is: " + dealerScore);

        if (dealerScore <= 15 && playerScore > dealerScore) tempScore = cards.rollDice();
        System.out.println("The dice roll was: " + tempScore);
        dealerScore += tempScore;
        System.out.println("Dealer score is: " + dealerScore);

    }

    public static void playerRoll() {
        while (newGame) {
            cards.rollDice();
        }

        playerScore = (cards.rollDice());

        System.out.println("You total is " + playerScore);

        while (playerScore < 21 || playerScore < dealerScore) {

            System.out.println("Would you like to take a hit? y or n?");
            hit = scan.nextLine();
            if (hit.equals("y")) {
                tempScore = cards.rollDice();
                System.out.println("The dice roll was: " + tempScore);
                playerScore += tempScore;
                System.out.println("Your score is now: " + playerScore);

            }
            else if (hit.equals("n")); {
                checkWinner();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void checkWinner() {
        if (playerScore == 21) System.out.println("You win!");
        else if (dealerScore == 21) System.out.println("Sorry, Dealer has won!");
        else if (dealerScore > playerScore) System.out.println("Sorry, Dealer has won!");
        else if (playerScore > dealer) System.out.println("You win!");
        else if (playerScore > 21) System.out.println("Sorry you busted, Dealer has won!");

        else if (dealerScore > 21) System.out.println("Dealer has busted, You win!");
    }
}​
```

Comment: first of all your `while (newGame) { ... }` loops are going to run forever if `newGame` is true because there's no way for `newGame` to become false within the loop.

Comment: yeah I just realized that when i posted the code, I changed it to compare the strings instead of the references.

Comment: I'm just going to mention, `cards.rollDice()` made me do a double take.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check winner when you complete the player turn.  do it only after the dealer turn.

Answer (score 0):

I redid the code and came up with this. Any comments would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;


public class BlackJack
{
    static PairOfDice cards = new PairOfDice();
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int playerScore, dealerScore, player, dealer, tempScore, takeHit, stand;
    private static boolean playGame;
    static String play= "y", yesPlay;
    static char hit;


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        newGame();



    }

    public static void newGame()
    {
        do
        {

            playerRoll();
            dealerRoll();
            stand();
            checkWinner();
            System.out.println("Would you like to play again? (Y/N)");
        } while (scan.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0) == 'y');

    }

    public static int takeHit()
    {
        return takeHit = cards.rollDice();
    }

    public static  int stand()
    {
        return playerScore;


    }

    public static void dealerRoll()
    {
        while(playGame)
        {
            cards.rollDice();
        }

        dealerScore = (cards.rollDice());



                do
                {
                    tempScore = takeHit();

                //System.out.println("The dice roll was: " + tempScore);
                dealerScore += tempScore;
                System.out.println("Dealer score is: " + dealerScore);
                }while(dealerScore <= 15 && playerScore > dealerScore);


    }

    public static void playerRoll()
    {
        while(playGame)
        {
            cards.rollDice();
        }

        playerScore = (cards.rollDice());

            System.out.println("Your total is " + playerScore);


            System.out.println("Would you like a hit?(Y/N)");
            hit = scan.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);

            if(hit == 'y')
                do
                {
                    tempScore = takeHit();
                    //System.out.println("The dice roll was: " + tempScore);
                    System.out.println("The hit gave you : " + tempScore + " Your total is now: " + (playerScore += tempScore));
                    System.out.println("Would you like a hit?(Y/N)");
                }while(scan.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0) == 'y');



            if(hit == 'n')
                        stand();









    }

    public static void checkWinner()
    {
        if (playerScore > 21)
            System.out.println("Sorry you busted, Dealer has won!");
        else
        if (dealerScore > 21)
                System.out.println("Dealer has busted, You win!");
        else 
        if (playerScore == 21)
            System.out.println("You win!");
        else
        if (dealerScore == 21)
            System.out.println("Sorry, Dealer has won!");
        else if (dealerScore > playerScore && dealerScore <= 21)
            System.out.println("Sorry, Dealer has won!");
        else if (playerScore > dealer && playerScore <= 21)
            System.out.println("You win!");





    }
```